# How to change link of a PDF file uploaded in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pdf, upload

This is my actual link to my pdf uploaded file:

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/my_pdf_file.pdf

I would like to change it to

```
http://example.com/my_pdf_file.pdf
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/faq/). You install that, go to **Tools > Redirection** and add your source and target urls there.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/bsk-pdf-manager/

This plugin can help you do it easily but it need to have a URL base before your pdf slug. It can help you make the permalink likes http://example.com/bsk-pdf-manager/my-pdf-file/

In its Pro version you may change the URL base name and make your permalink likes:
http://example.com/guide/my-pdf-file/

Answer (score 0):

yes...
you not change exiting link but you upload new documents without year and month in link..
go to settings > media > off Uploading file